# What is correct PowerIso command to create an .iso file for each folder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Inside **C:\temp** I have 12 folders

```
one
two
three
four
...
```

I try to use **piso.exe** command line to create a .iso file for each folder.

```
one.iso
two.iso
...
```

Ok, I open CMD and I try to use these commands

```
set piso="%programfiles%\PowerIso\piso.exe"
cd C:\temp
for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o  d:\%temp.iso -add d:\%temp
```

but it fails, also `-add` seems to be a bad parameter.

Any idea to solve ?

Comment: So you are using a `FOR` command but not even using any of its output?  Why are you not using `%a`?  For the sake of simplicity I would just use a `FOR /D` command instead of parsing the output of the `DIR` command with a `FOR /F`.  The `FOR /D` is specifically meant for iterating directory names.

Comment: If you want to know what the correct syntax for PowerISO is I would highly recomment you go directly to the source and read the [PowerISO Tutorials](https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/).

Comment: **FOR /D %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o  d:\%a.iso** doesn't work, it say me "device not ready"

Comment: I see you clearly did not read the syntax usage for the `FOR /D` option nor did you understand my previous comment about it.  A `FOR /F` command is used to parse output of other commands. I told you to use a `FOR /D` in place of parsing the output of the `DIR` with a `FOR /F`.  That means you should not be using the `DIR` command or the `FOR /F` option.  If you read the help file. `FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command` **If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory names**

Comment: I try with `piso create -o d:\one.iso` but it says that "device is not ready". Too complicated for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: To refer to the environment variable `temp`, use `%temp%` rather than `%temp`! only `for` meta-variables are referred to `%a`, unless they are used in a batch file, then you need `%%a` (type for /?` and read the output help text very carefully!)…

Comment: A way could be with `for d in */; do piso.exe -o "${a%/}.iso" "$a"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
set piso="%programfiles%\PowerIso\piso.exe"

cd C:\temp2

for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o  "C:\%a.iso" -add "C:\temp2" /
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).